# How to make a link to a .desktop [Desktop Entry] file

Tags: permissions, files

I made a link on my Desktop to the launcher file "Compiz" in /usr/share/applications/. When I try to execute it I get:

"The application launcher "Link to compiz.desktop" has not been marked as trusted. If you do not know the source of this file, launching it may be unsafe."

So my question is how to make such a launcher on my Desktop?

Otherwise, what kind of file are these [Desktop Entry] files and how can they be executed (by double clicking on them) if they have permissions such as:

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   396 2010-12-17 15:23 compiz.desktop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a security policy you can't "execute" .desktop files from nautilus unless they have +x (execute permission).
Because you have created a symbolick link you must set the +x on the original desktop file, open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/share/applications/compiz.desktop
```

Please note that the +x maybe lost if the compiz package get's updated, it's probably a better idea to copy the .desktop file and set the +x on your copy.

Comment: Thank you. Anyway, you say you can't "execute" a .desktop file unless it has the x permission, but the original one had -rw-r--r-- and I could execute it by double clicking on it; why is it so?

Comment: Eventually this security policy only applies to Desktop items.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a reason to use a link to `/usr/share/applications/compiz.desktop`?
If you simply copy it to your Desktop you will be able to *Mark as Trusted* :

[image]