# How do I get and keep access to encrypted home dir on an external drive?

Tags: permissions, encryption, ecryptfs

I have a clean new install of 12.04 on my internal drive.  On my external drive I have everything that used to be on this drive.  The file I'm concerned with right now is my old home folder from 10.04.

When I open it with nautilus it allows me change the permissions but when I get inside the old home folder I have 2 items, `Access-your-private-date.desktop` and `ReadMe.text`.

This is what `readme.text` says:

```
THIS DIRECTORY HAS BEEN UNMOUNTED TO PROTECT YOUR DATA.

From the graphical desktop, click on:
 "Access Your Private Data"

or

From the command line, run:
 ecryptfs-mount-private
```

I tried entering that last line into a terminal and nothing changed.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is the UNencrypted view of an encrypted home directory, see (read) the `README.txt` (spelling and case matter!). I'm sure you can adapt the answer from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44514/accessing-home-directory-of-encryted-ubuntu-its-on-a-usb-stick-and-refuses-to-b/) answer.

Comment: Thank you.  I not only read but reposted the readme.text file. I don't know where to mount the directory.  I'm new to 12.04 and never had to mount anything but a drive or partition. When I click on "Access your private data" I get an error         "The application launcher "Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop" has not been marked as trusted. If you do not know the source of this file, launching it may be unsafe."  I don't know how to mark it as trusted.  There are no options here other than to close the error message.

Comment: @hortstu: Right click on the `.desktop` and click properties, permissions, and set it as executable. See also: http://askubuntu.com/q/20951/2355